# Do "\a" and the Console.Beep() method play the same beep?

Tags: c#, .net, escaping, beep

`\a` is an [*`escape sequence`*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) which represents a *bell alert* on character constants. On [`Console.Beep()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hftfeyw.aspx) method explanation from *MSDN*:

> Plays the sound of a beep through the console speaker.

Let's consider this sample code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Console.WriteLine("\a");
     Console.Beep();
}
```

This code creates 2 beeps and they sounds the same to me. Now I need to see the proof.

When I decompile the [`Console.Beep()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hftfeyw.aspx) method, it uses `Win32Native.Beep` from *kernel32.dll*;

```
public static void Beep(int frequency, int duration)
{
    Win32Native.Beep(frequency, duration);
}
```

Their frequencies and durations can be different, I don't say anything about these stuff but are their sources the same (`Win32Native.Beep`)? Which source does `\a` use for the *bell alert*?

Comment: I'd say these are different, as `\a` is not something you can supply a frequency or duration for. Of course, the OS may end up calling the same code under the hoods with hard coded values when presented with `\a`.

Comment: However, rather academic, no? Not a real problem you are facing, eh?

Comment: @Oded Yeah, that's not a _big_ problem which I faced, but I always wondering it if they are or not. Of course `\a` doesn't have frequency or duration, but I prefer a proof beside just calling them _different_.

Comment: What kind of proof do you want? By checking audio or checking the code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is as far as I could gather from examining the audio (Windows 7 64-bit (yes, I had to reboot into windows, I'm that dedicated :) ). I recorded the audio using Fraps, so it should be reliable.

This is the code I used to check them:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("\a");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.Beep();
        }
    }
}
```

These are the two tracks in Audacity (`Console.Write('\a')` being the upper one, `Console.Beep()` the lower).

[image: Two beeps]

At any point where I zoomed in on the tracks, the sine waves exactly matched each other, and they had the exact same duration, so I have to conclude that they are, in fact, the same (on Windows 7 that is).

Comment: Well, thanks for answering and your effort but I actually wondering they use the same dll or not. But unfortunately, I think we never know which dll `\a` using for its alert.

Comment: @SonerGönül And that code will probably vary among versions of windows, making it even more complicated.